# New Chrome Inspect Toolbar

Tags: google-chrome

This just appeared in the top left of my window when I run Chrome Inspect.

[image]

What is it called and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is "[device mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)" mobile/layout emulation. The key to disabling it is finding the phone icon, usually at the top left of the normal inspector window. The icon should be blue while it is active.

In this image, you can see it at the bottom right:

[image: device mode phone icon]

The disable icon on the top left looks promising, but only turns off the emulation of a specific mobile device; it doesn't actually close the device mode view.